# Язык C, atexit(), MinGW, Windows

Tags: c, windows, mingw

Пытаюсь понять, как работает **atexit()**. Ясное дело, что она регистрирует функции, которые будут вызваны при нормальном завершении процесса.

Мне необходимо дождаться записи файла, даже если пользователь внезапно прервет процесс: например, нажмет на крестик консоли/главного окна.

Я начал с простого - зарегистрировал функцию, которая ждет 10 секунд, чтобы проверить наличие внутреннего таймаута для вызываемых функций:

```
void func(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("+\n");
        _sleep(1000);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    atexit(func);// Пока без проверки успешности.
    _sleep(-1);
}
```

После закрытия консоли на крестик, запускается функция **func()**, но выводится не 10 плюсов, а всего 5.

Если же завершить процесс через диспетчер задач, то выводится один плюс.

Объясните, как это работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что вы хотите, чтоб человек, которого убивают на улице выстрелом в спину (читай - крестиком на консоли), был в состоянии перед смертью еще и завещание написать?

Это функция для *штатного* завершения - когда надо какие-то файлы закрыть или что еще сделать по очистке при *штатном* завершении. Даже `abort()` - уже не считается штатным завершением.

Comment: А крестик не считается корректным завершение программы?

Comment: помню, как меня просили уметь закрывать транзакцию, если свет выключают. А купить бесперебойник - не, так каждый умеет.

Comment: Каким механизмом в таком случае возможно защитить записываемый файл от повреждения?

Comment: А файл повреждается?

Comment: Повреждается в том смысле, что процесс "слива" N байт в файл (например, структуры), прерывается на полпути.

Comment: Тут все зависит от того, как именно пишете. Если данные в буфер поместились, то ось сама допишет (если физически может) и файл закроет. Если же структуру по байтику писать и sleep'ами разбавить, то да, будут проблемы. Для хорошей надежности можно обычной базой данных воспользоваться, если лень все самому писать.

Comment: Я понял, куда копать, спасибо.

Comment: @KoVadim Знавал я мужика (в 90-х), который как-то прибежал с проблемой - комп поломался, чекдиск при загрузке не работает... Выяснилось - он просто выключал питание, ну, Винда и запускала чекдиск на входе... А тут кто-то за ним аккуратно машину выключил.

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться функцией [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler). В документации и пример использования также имеется.

Comment: У такого варианта тоже есть таймаут на выполнение функции перед завершением, как и у atexit().

Answer (score 0):

можно попробовать поработать с сигналами. Что то вроде

```
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
```

Ну и SIGKILL, в документации описано. Может сработает

Comment: является ответом. Поставить строчку и проверить ситуацию. Два сигнала, две строчки. Любой сишник поймет, если он программист